# How to link statically with sub module

Tags: protocol-buffers, autoconf, automake

I am building a package that uses sub-module (protobuf) that I wand to link with statically, and avoid providing it's binaries in the package I build.

I did the following:

1. Add protobuf as sub-module of my project.
2. Use autoconf to build only static library using: --with-pic=yes --enable-
   shared=no flags.
3. Avoid invoking "make install" (only make) on the sub-module.

Currently the package building process fails when running distcheck.
According to error message, it fails on distcheck of the sub-module, since the binaries of the sub-module are not included.

Is there a guide for how to properly build and link statically with sub modules ?
(and avoid including them in the packages)